# WebCamTexture not working on windows phone 10

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, windows-phone, webcam, windows-10-mobile

I try to open webCam of my phone with unity3d.

```
myWebCameraTexture = new WebCamTexture();
myCameraTexture.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.mainTexture =myWebCameraTexture;
myWebCameraTexture.Play();
```

When I publish my application on my phone, camera not start. Why? Any solution? I try to put a plane, where I have a Render with an material but still not working.

Comment: What Unity version? Does this code work in the Editor?

Comment: 5.4, yes It works, on my pc when I run my application camera is turn on.

Comment: @Programmer any solution?

Comment: Did you check Webcam capability in the Package.appxmanifest?

Comment: @AndreyAshikhmin I believe that Unity is suppose to add that automatically.  Jijie,  I didn't find anything about this problem. You should file for bug report and let Unity take a look at this.

Comment: Webcam capability in the Package.appxmanifest is checked. You need to add manualy.